# Displaying Bootbox modal scrolled down hiding scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, modal-dialog, bootbox

Using "bootbox.dialog" I present a long modal containing DataTable loading from external ajax. I want the modal to be presented scrolled to its bottom.

First, I tried scrolling down by triggering `window.location.href` to an anchor located at the bottom of the modal but couldn't find the right callback in order to trigger the vent only when the the whole table finish to display.

Then, I tried replacing the `top: 0; bottom: 0;` in css and it the modal indeed display in its bottom but for some reason the scrollbar does not appear - although set to `overflow-y: auto;`.

Is there a way to fix it? I would prefer an option that will enable to also animate the scrolling to the bottom to be slow but this is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
                    var dialog = bootbox.dialog()

                    dialog.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                        dialog.animate({ scrollTop: 9999}, 'slow');
                    });
```